# Get field of document Cloud Firestore (AndroidStudio-Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

When I do query to get user's nickname I can read nickname, but I can't take the variable out with correct nickname out of query.

```
//Get data from login user (authentication user)
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser

//Get his mail
val mail = user?.email.toString()

//Do query to get nickname (from users collection with user's mail)
val usuaris = db.collection("usuaris")
val query = usuaris.whereEqualTo("mail", mail).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                        document ->
                    if (document != null){
                     //save document to val usuari
                     val usuari = document.toObjects(Usuari::class.java)
                     //save string nickname to usuariStr
                     usuariStr = usuari[0].nickname
                     //the log show the correct nickname
                     Log.i("usuari_query",usuariStr)
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
}

//The usuariStr= "" is deleted when exit from query, and I can't read nickname

//dataclass to get nickname from query
data class Usuari(var adreca: String = "", var cognoms: String ="", var contrasenya:String="",
                  var mail: String="", var nickname: String="", var nom: String="",
                  var poblacio: String="", var telefon:String="")
```

Comment: I try to use a function to do the insert into query, and it works. I don't  know if it's the better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct, the solution is put a function inside the .addOnSuccessListener to do an update, insert or manipulate the result.